# Как сделать так, что бы после закрытия дочерней формы, можно было второй раз зайти на нее по клику на лейбл( на основной форме)?

Tags: c#

Когда в первый раз нажимаю на лейбл с ссылкой на дочернюю, открывается как надо. После, закрываю форму по кнопке (Application.Exit). Второе нажатие на тот же лейбл вызывает ошибку. Помогите, пожалуйста
`

```
    public remake rere = new remake();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AddOwnedForm(rere);
        }
private void label4_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            rere.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            rere.Show();
        }
```

`

Comment: Дочернюю форму надо закрывать `Close()`, а не `Application.Exit()`

Comment: А если надо иметь один и тот же экземпляр дочерней формы, и показывать/скрывать по желанию - то её можно ещё и прятать - rere.Hide().